# Where is syslog.conf?

Tags: configuration, syslog

I tried to move my stuff from CentOS to Ubuntu. Here is a problem I met: I would like find the corresponding CentOS /etc/syslog.conf file in Ubuntu? Basically, the file is used to control where those syslog files go?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Ubuntu uses [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/), config files are `rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*`

Comment: rsyslog.conf in /etc folder (/etc/rsyslog.conf)

Answer (score 1):

Minor addition:

Ubuntu uses `rsyslog.conf (5)` configuration file and the daemon is `rsyslogd (8)` is a rocket-fast system for log processing.

`Rsyslog.conf` is backward-compatible  with syslogd's `syslog.conf` file. So if you migrate from syslogd you can rename it and it should work.